# Winning a playoff game without ever leading in regulation in the NBA

Tags: basketball, nba, postseason

The Cleveland Cavaliers beat the Toronto Raptors in overtime of opening game of the second round series of 2017-2018 season playoffs. The Cavs won the game despite never leading in regulation time, their first lead was in early overtime. Watching TSN, it was mentioned that the Cavs where just the second team to win a playoffs game while never leading in regulation time in the past 20 years.

What are all teams that won a playoffs game without ever leading in regulation time in the history of the NBA?

Answer (score 1):

Mavericks at Thunder on May 23, 2011, has accomplished the same.

Source : https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/sports/wp/2018/05/01/nba-playoffs-game-1-cavaliers-raptors-game-2-warriors-pelicans/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.901288f53d27